# How to code communication between two enc28j60?

Tags: avr, embedded, network-interface, enc28j60

I am new to embedded programming and enc28j60. I am developing a project which includes two boards with Enc28j60. The working of the system is explained below.

board 1 :  It will request data from board2 over enc28j60.
board 2 : It will sample a sensor data at the rate of 10khz upto 4500 samples. sample number can vary. This board have to transfer this sampled values to board 1 over enc28j60.

board 1 : atmega328p interfaced with Enc28j60.
board 2 : atmega328p interfaced with Enc28j60 and a sensor.

In the board2, the sensor part is already written.

Now my problem is the communication between two enc28j60. By reading the datasheet, i have done some code. As a initial steps i coded initialisation of MAC and PHY registers. Also written code for transmitting ethernet packet.

But I confused while searching about Enc28j60 communication on google. In almost all forums show enc28j60 is used for udp and tcp communication.  From the datasheet i didn't find such type of communication. Datasheet only speaks about MAC and PHY communication.

For my application, whether udp or tcp is needed? How to complete my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you to decide if IP/TCP/UDP makes sense. You know what the purpose of these protocols is, right: communicating on very, very large scale networks, composed of very different kind of computers. Bascially: what Internet is.

Do you need that?

If all you need is just your two devices communicating in a point-to-point fashion, with a simple cat5 cable between them, then nothing prevents you to send raw ethernet packets and forget about all the IP stuff. Nothing prevents you to implement your own, very simple protocol.

In any case, the ENC28J60 datasheet sure won't explain how to do TCP communication, because this protocol isn't specific to the ENC28J60. To understand how TCP works, you need to read the appropriate RFCs. The chip doesn't care at all what protocol you use above the MAC layer.

That's what the OSI layers are about: separating the concerns.

Comment: Is that possible to test the MAC layer communication using PC? because I written code for transmitting a packet, I have a atmega328 with Enc28j60. Is to possible to see the packet on PC by conmecting it with RJ45 cable.

Comment: Using PC for debugging would be a very good argument for implementing a higher level protocol like UDP or TCP.

Comment: @mcv I think so, if you use some network sniffer tool, like WireShark. I think they're able to sniff packets at the MAC layer, not just IP (but check the documentation). Also, you'll probably be able to see the packets coming from your board, but I'm not sure you'll be able to easily send raw packets from the PC to your board to test the reception part.

Comment: I tried to do the same. I think enc28j60 is not responding since no leds are blinking. But the power led of enc28j60 module blinks.

Comment: Can you suggest best library to use for a UDP communication?

Comment: @mcv There are lots of them. I believe "lwip" is used in quite some projects, but there are others. "Best library" doesn't mean much anyway... According to which criteria?

Comment: I need to work on AVR studio since existing code was developed on the same ide. We are going to add this feature to existing code.